# How to save the data of ReactQuill in mongoDB and getback with same styling features?

Tags: reactjs, rich-text-editor, react-quill

I am using **ReactQuill** text editor. When I am sending the content of editor into the MongoDB The styling of the content getting lost except Bold and paragraph tag. I want to know how I can store all data with styling and get back with the same.
I am updating state using the editor.getContent()
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDM1P.png)
The props that I am passing into ReactQuill
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKpe7.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TylAt.png)

Comment: Please share which props are you passing to the react quill component

Comment: I am passing modules, formats, value and onChange props to the react quill component. I add the image of code in question.